# Android layout optimization, avoiding layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout

It seems like, the use of layout_weight in relative layouts (needed to inflate a ListView) is quite heavy in low cpu phones.

How could I optimize this layout?

How important it is to specify min Width and Height on each widget?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LLHFila"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cmdReducir"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/minus50px"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LLVProducto"
        android:layout_weight="3">
        <TextView
            android:text="Long Description Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblProducto" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/LLHmontos">
            <TextView
                android:text="Amount"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lblCantidad"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Price"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lblImporte"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cmdAumentar"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/plus50px"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is the listview?

Comment: This is only the Relative Layout that would later be inflated to create a ListView

Comment: Using `layout_weight` in `RelativeLayout` makes no sence. But using `layout_weight` with nested layouts may lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

This basically eliminated all nesting. And as @Onik suggested, there is no sense on using weight with RelativeLayout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cmdReducir"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/minus50px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
<TextView
    android:text="Long Description Title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lblProducto"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cmdReducir"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cmdAumentar"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" />
<TextView
    android:text="Amount"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lblCantidad"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblProducto"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cmdReducir"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
<TextView
    android:text="Price"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lblImporte"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblProducto"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cmdAumentar"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cmdAumentar"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/plus50px"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one support library introduced by android [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/package-summary.html)

Hope this help you as this is very interesting and every one is liking this !!

In this you can define a view width or height by some precent. It has has two pre-built layouts – the `PercentRelativeLayout` and the `PercentFrameLayout`.

Use : 
add dependency in build.gradle of app

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
```

and in xml

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout

  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

  android:layout_width="match_parent"

  android:layout_height="match_parent"

  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

  tools:context=".MainActivity">


  <Button

    android:id="@+id/button"

    android:text="Button"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    app:layout_widthPercent="30%"/>


  <Button    

    android:id="@+id/button2"

    android:text="Button 2"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button"

    app:layout_widthPercent="60%"/>


  <Button

    android:id="@+id/button3"

    android:text="Button 3"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_below="@+id/button"

    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    app:layout_widthPercent="90%"/>


</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

This code is taken from [LINK](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/)